# How do I Create a Loop from Raw_Input String Value

Tags: python, loops

What I'm trying to do with my program is to ask a user to enter a input string that will later  be converted to uppercase or lowercase using str.upper or str.lower.

I have 5 sets options that the user can chose:

```
a = 'convert to upper case'
b =  'convert to lower case'
c = 'switch case of every alphabetic character to the opposite case'
d = 'convert first and last chrs of each word to upper case, and others to lower'
e = 'no change'
```

So far I have done the conversion for options a and b. But before I move forward creating a code for options c, d and e. I'm trying to create a loop but I'm not sure how to do it using raw_input and strings.

This is the code that I have so far:

```
# Conversion Rules

a = 'convert to upper case'
b =  'convert to lower case'
c = 'switch case of every alphabetic character to the opposite case'
d = 'convert first and last chrs of each word to upper case, and others to lower'
e = 'no change'


def upper(): 
    print 'Your Input: %s' % choice
    print 'Choosen Conversion Rule: %s' % a
    return 'Conversion Result: %s' % option_A

def lower(): 
    print 'Your Input: %s' % choice
    print 'Choosen Conversion Rule: %s' % b
    return 'Conversion Result: %s' % option_B


choice = str(raw_input('Choose an Option:'))    


if (choice == 'A') or (choice == 'a'): 
    value_A = str(raw_input('Enter a String to Convert:'))
    option_A = str.upper(Value_A) 
    print upper()

elif (choice == 'B') or ('b'): 
    value_B = str(raw_input('Enter a String to Convert:'))
    option_B = str.lower(value_B) 
    print lower()  

else:

    print 'Goodbye' # Here I want to break if 'Q' is entered if 'Q' is entered.
```

So after the user enters an option. For example 'A' or 'a'. The first condition will run but then I want to add a loop that goes back to the beginning of the code and allows the user to enter the option again or choose a different option so a different condition will run.

```
choice = str(raw_input('Choose an Option:'))    


    if (choice == 'A') or (choice == 'a'): 
        value_A = str(raw_input('Enter a String to Convert:'))
        option_A = str.upper(Value_A) 
        print upper()

# I want to add a loop here to go back to the 'choice' variable.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put all of your user-interface inside a while loop that loops forever (until for example some key is presses).

```
# Conversion Rules
a = 'convert to upper case'
b =  'convert to lower case'
c = 'switch case of every alphabetic character to the opposite case'
d = 'convert first and last chrs of each word to upper case, and others to lower'
e = 'no change'

def upper(): 
    print 'Your Input: %s' % choice
    print 'Choosen Conversion Rule: %s' % a
    return 'Conversion Result: %s' % option_A

def lower(): 
    print 'Your Input: %s' % choice
    print 'Choosen Conversion Rule: %s' % b
    return 'Conversion Result: %s' % option_B

while True:
    choice = str(raw_input('Choose an Option:'))    

    if (choice == 'A') or (choice == 'a'): 
        value_A = str(raw_input('Enter a String to Convert:'))
        option_A = str.upper(Value_A) 
        print upper()
    elif (choice == 'B') or ('b'): 
        value_B = str(raw_input('Enter a String to Convert:'))
        option_B = str.lower(value_B) 
        print lower()  
    else:
        print 'Goodbye' # Here I want to break if 'Q' is entered if 'Q' is entered.
        break
```

Note that the "break" is what breaks you out of the loop.  Since the user-interface part is in the while loop, it will repeat.